# Consecutive 'is' operator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can somebody explain this for me?

```
>>> None is None is None
True
>>> (None is None) is None
False
```

Doesn't the 'is' operator take 2 operands, compare objects from the left, and return Boolean?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, the other question implies that one knows the chained expression feature and asks if it is applicable to `is`.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer mm, I leave it up to you if you want to re-open it. Frequently, people will dupe-target the famous [Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) when another questions is really asking about *unexplained* behavior they are seeing as a result of it. I bet there are other potential duplicates, though.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I admit this is a duplicate, but I really couldn't find those article or references, so I had to ask.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga fine with me

Comment: @vbstb: no worries, without knowing the term "chained expression", finding references to this feature is pretty hard.

Comment: @Ferdinand Beyer Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is being interpreted as a [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

```
comparison    ::=  or_expr ( comp_operator or_expr )*
comp_operator ::=  "<" | ">" | "==" | ">=" | "<=" | "!="
                   | "is" ["not"] | ["not"] "in"
```

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent
>   to `x < y and y <= z`, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases z is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if `a, b, c, …, y, z` are expressions and `op1, op2, …, opN` are
>   comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to
>   `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is
>   evaluated at most once.

Thus, since `is` is a comparison operator, your first expression is equivalent to:

```
None is None and None is None
```

Comment: How did this get downvoted?

Comment: @MadPhysicist probably because it was a duplicate. I probably should have known.

Comment: Does this mean that `None is not 5 < 10` will be `True` as well, since mixing comparison operators if fine?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yep

Answer (score -1):

Compare with `2 < 3 < 4`.

Is the 2nd None the same as the 1st None? Yes. Is the 3rd same as the 2nd? Yes.

OTOH, `(True) is None` is clearly False. The parentheses broke the chaining.

Evaluating `lo < n < hi` is a common python idiom, and that doesn't make you worried about an intermediate result of `True < 4`. Evaluating `x is y is z` is less common, but for your singleton `None` the three objects are identical.

Comment: This does not explain anything. Why is this the case? Just because some other, unrelated, operator has a similar behavior?